# Eclipse crashed and won't restart

Tags: eclipse, crash

I had to run a program that's supposed to write 8 MB to a file and then read it, timing each read and write along the way. Eclipse crashed and won't restart, and I dont have the metadata resources .snap file that other threads said to delete to fix the problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try to restart it? There should be *some* kind of output you can tell us about, or updated or created log files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience long time ago and solved the issue, try delete file **workbench.xmi** in 
 [Drive]:\ [ProjectFolder]\ .metadata\ .plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\